# How to call out multiple JSON objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to call multiple objects from my JSON file for various different sections on my site. As it stands i have the jobs and a misc section for section titles etc. With my HTML i have the following

```
<h2>{{job.jobTitle}}</h2>
```

This works fine. However the misc section doesn't display any content

```
<h1>{{title.widgetTitle}}</h1>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
"jobs": [
    {
        "jobTitle": "Senior Accountant",
        "sector": "Accounting & Finance",
        "link": "/jobs/1"
    },
 ],
 "title": [
            {"widgetTitle": "Latest Jobs"}

         ]
```

HTML

```
 <div class="tickr-container" data-ng-controller="tickCtrl">
            <div>   
                <h1>{{title[0].widgetTitle}}</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h3>{{date | date:'fullDate' : 'GMT'}}</h3>

                <ul ng-mouseover="stopAuto()" ng-mouseleave="startAuto()" class="tickrSlider">
                    <li class="tickrSlider-slide" ng-class="{'job-active' :isActive($index)}" data-ng-repeat="job in jobs">
                        <div class="tickrSlider-inner">
                            <h2>{{job.jobTitle}}</h2>
                            <p>{{job.sector}}</p>
                            <a class="tickrSlide-info" href="{{job.link}}">{{job.link}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Your json in plunkr is missing the "misc" section. You have invalid html there as well. Unclosed a, div, nav tags.

Comment: @HenriHietala that's that's a typo from copying and pasting my code. The misc section is "title"

Comment: It's because widgetTitle is inside an array. Try: `{{title[0].widgetTitle}}`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you reference `title[0].widgetTitle`?

`<h2>{{job.jobTitle}}</h2>` appears fine since you reference the `job` object from `data-ng-repeat="job in jobs"`

Comment: i am assume in order to display objects within the title array in will be title in titles etc ?

Comment: Yep, just like you did with 'jobs'